# Pasting a large amount of text in a TextArea leads to a script execution timeout

Tags: apache-flex, flash, performance

(Flex 3) I have a TextArea component which needs to hold the user's clipboard content. The TextArea does the job relatively well for most cases but when pasting a large amount of data, I can't seem to get the content in the component at all due to the script execution timeout.

I've done a fair deal on investigation to try and hopefully find how I could make this work.
I found that the TextArea is using a IUITextField (which is in my case an instance of TextField at runtime) do handle the job of obtaining the pasting data and then throws an event when it is done.

I have found no way to take a look at the source of TextField as it is a class in the playerglobal.swc library.

Is there a way for me to maybe see the source of that class or is there something I'm missing in my approach to figure out a way to make this work?

P.S: I know there would be alternate way to achieve the results I'm looking for but I would like to make this particular solution work.

Comment: "large amount of data" isn't specific enough for testing, would you like to post an example?

Comment: it is about 7mb of text. i've tested a bare application with a simple text area, no styling, no handler and i'm having the same issue.

Comment: maybe I should say that I'm probably more interested in some pointer to help me continue debugging this issue myself more than a solution to my problem.

Comment: Just trying to render 5 mb of plain text from a notepad doc will not even render under 5 minutes. I say 5 because that is when I gave up and ended the tast. I would strongly suggest not going this route.

Comment: You know, that when you manage somehow to put 7MB of text into a textarea, the whole application will slow down so much, that you are unable to do anything? Doing something like entering a single letter, or scrolling down will cause script timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its impossible with such large texts (you mentioned that the text is around 7MB).

If you look at the source of mx:TextArea, it inserts text simply be setting its TextField text property to the string you entered:
From TextArea.as around line 2050:

```
 if (textChanged || htmlTextChanged)
    {
        // If the 'text' and 'htmlText' properties have both changed,
        // the last one set wins.
        if (isHTML)
            textField.htmlText = explicitHTMLText;
        else
            textField.text = _text;

        textFieldChanged(false, true)

        textChanged = false;
        htmlTextChanged = false;
    }
```

If you make a sample app with a TextField and try to set its text property with a large string, you will get script timeouts. (i got timeout when i tried it with a string length of 1MB):

```
   import flash.text.TextField;
    tf = new TextField();
    addChild(tf);
    tf.multiline = true;
    tf.wordWrap = true;
    tf.width= 600
    tf.height = 500
    var str:String = "";
    for (var i:int=0; i<100000; i++) {
        str = str+"0123456789"
    }
    tf.text = str
```

This is the simplest possible way to display text, and it timeouts. Flex will try to do a dozen of more things with this textfield before laying out...so it will give up at much smaller size texts too.

The only possible solution is to make a custom textfield, and add the text gradually - Adobe recommends to use TextField.appendText():

```
import flash.text.TextField;
public function test(){
    tf = new TextField();
    addChild(tf);
    tf.multiline = true;
    tf.wordWrap = true;
    tf.width= 600
    tf.height = 500
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEF);
}

private var cnt:int = 0;

private function onEF(event:Event):void{
    if (cnt>200) return;
    trace (cnt);
    var str:String = "";
        //pasting around 50K at once seems ideal.
    for (var i:int=0; i<5000; i++) {
        str = str+"0123456789"
    }
    tf.appendText(str);
    cnt++;
}
```

This script manages to add 10MB of text into the TextField... although after adding 1MB it gets increasingly slower (it took around 1 sec for an iteration at the end). And if you try to do *anything* with this textfield (for example resizing, modifying text not with appendText(), adding it to the stage after its complete...) you will get script timeout.

So the complete solution is to capture the paste event canvas wrapper trick (William's solution), and then add the text gradually to a custom component, that uses appendText to add text. (use flash.text.TextField, and add it to the stage with mx_internal::$addChild() ). I have not tested, whether you can remove the resulting monstrosity with removeChild without triggering a script timeout :).

Comment: My problem isn't about actually showing the text to the user, I think nobody is interested in reading 5mb+ of text they just pasted. I'll probably just get away with it by showing parts of the text at once.

Answer (score 3):

Since the TextField doesn't want to accept our paste event we will find someone else who will. Here is the mx:TextArea workaround:

MXML:

```
<mx:Canvas id="canvas" paste="pasteHandler(event)">
    <mx:TextArea id="textArea" textInput="if (event.text.length > 1) event.preventDefault();" 
     keyDown="keyDown(event)" mouseEnabled="false"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

AS:

```
private function keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //When CTRL-V is pressed set focus to canvas
    if(event.keyCode==86 && event.ctrlKey)
        canvas.setFocus();
}
```

You also need enable the clipboard items on the Canvas's ContextMenu and reset focus to TextArea when finished with the paste.

Got the paste-blocking solution from: [flex: how to prevent PASTE (ctrl+V) in a flex3 textinput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530397/flex-how-to-prevent-paste-ctrlv-in-a-flex3-textinput)

Answer (score 2):

This problem will often occur when large amounts of antialiased text are added to the display list.  Once the text is rendered, everything is fine again.  You can go around this problem, if you're handling predefined text, by splitting large portions of text into a lot of small ones, and adding them to the stage piece by piece (say, 20 lines of text at a time), waiting one frame between each, allowing the screen to refresh.

I haven't tried this yet, but I would suggest adding an event listener to the TextArea and checking on `Event.RENDER`, if the text was changed.  If this is true, you could remove all text that was added since the last render event, and frame by frame re-add it much like in the example above.

Also, try using native instead of embedded fonts and switching off antialiasing, or reducing its quality.

Comment: The Event.Render method does not work - No event is launched between the moment I press CTRL+V and the TextArea's TextInput has finished rendering/processing my text.   I'm pretty sure all the work is done in a single frame and its the reason this process does a script time out. As for splitting the pasted text in smaller chunks, I'm not aware of anyway to act on whatever is happening when a component receives a clipboard 'paste' command. I will investigate further to try and disable anti aliasing for this particular component. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  I have come to the same conclusion as you did - all text rendering is done in a single frame, causing the player to hiccup.  It's a nuisance, but manageable when you're dealing with text you can portion, but damn near unsolvable when it's user input. :( I will do some research, too.  Maybe we can crack this one together.

Comment: Just to let you know: I have investigated further and found a way that _should_ work, but doesn't in practice:  From FlashPlayer 10 on, TextArea, as all other subclasses of InteractiveObject should fire a "paste" event, on which you can supposedly access the clipboard by calling Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData().  You could, then, process the content in the way described above.  Like I said, this should work, according to the Flash API.  The compiler even lets you code it.  The only problem is, the event never actually gets fired, and the clipboard can't be accessed on any other event.

Comment: There might be updated components somewhere out there, which actually do the things they are supposed to, but I have yet to find them. I'll update this, should I succeed... :(

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think that you can't intercept all types of user input event on text fields using Flex 3.

If you can switch to Flex 4 (thus using the new FTE), then you should add a listener on the `TextOperationEvent.CHANGING` event , that is a *cancellable* event. In the handler, you could verify the amount of text that is being added and, if it is too much, cancel the event (`event.preventDefault()`) and add it in multiple frames.

The nice thing about this event is that it fires also for event such as "delete key pressed with selected text", or cut/copy/paste/delete operations. In fact, I use it to apply early validation to some kind of text fields, that I couldn't detect in any way with Flex 3.

**EDIT**

**Maybe I found a solution**.. I noticed that the "restrict" property, that allows to filter the characters allowed in a text field, is supported in the built-in TextField class, and it is not a feature added by the wrapping Flex component: interesting for our porpuse.

So I tried to play with it, and I discovered that setting `restrict=""` on your TextArea will prevent blocking the UI on paste of a large block of text, because it is applied "early" at the player level. The nice thing is that, even with this setting, the TextArea will still dispatch the `textInput` event, so you can monitor the paste event and decide what to do with the new text: update the `text` property in a single step, start an incremental update or just ignore the event.

Copy and paste the following code to see an example (tested with Flex 3.6 and Flash Player 11):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
    layout="vertical"
    horizontalAlign="center">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function generateClipboard():void {
                var largeData:String = "";
                while (largeData.length < 1000000) {
                    largeData += "Lorem ipsum ... ";
                }
                System.setClipboard(largeData);
            }

            protected function ontextarea1_textInput(event:TextEvent):void {
                if (event.text.length < 100) {
                    // NAIVE CODE: just to demonstrate that you can
                    // programmatically modify the text.. you should "merge"
                    // the new text with existing content here
                    textArea.text += event.text;
                } else {
                    // do something here, like starting
                    // to add text block by block in
                    // multiple frames
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:TextArea id="textArea" width="100%" height="100%" restrict="" textInput="ontextarea1_textInput(event)"/>

    <mx:Button click="generateClipboard()" label="Set clipboard"/>

</mx:Application>
```

The tricky part will be correctly set the text on the textInput event, and the "incremental" load of large text.

Comment: Good explanation, similar to William's example. You are right about not being able to act on user input events in Flex 3, which is mainly the reason this problem does not seem fixable.

Answer (score 1):

In the Spark TextArea the Paste Event fires correctly. There might be a cleaner way to do this but this is the solution I found.

MXML:

```
<s:TextArea id="textArea" changing="changeHandler(event)" 
paste="pasteHandler(event)" />
```

AS:

```
private var pastedText:String;
private var textPosition:int=0;
//Number of characters to read per frame
private var chunkSize:int=1000;

private function changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void{
    if(String(event.operation)=="[object PasteOperation]"){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

private function pasteHandler(event:Event):void{
    pastedText = String(Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT));
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,frameHandler);
}

private function frameHandler(event:Event):void{
    if( textPosition + chunkSize > pastedText.length ){
        chunkSize = pastedText.length - textPosition;
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,frameHandler);
    }
    textArea.text += pastedText.substr(textPosition,chunkSize);
    textPosition += chunkSize;
}
```